# Prove series as a summation using induction?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

so sorry guys but I really have no clue what to do.

definition:

$a_{ n +1 } = ((a_{ n } + a_{ n-1})/2)$

$a_{ 0  } =0 $
$a_{ 1  } =1 $

now i have to show that

$$a_{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{ 1 }{ 2^{2 k-1 } } }$$

I already showed it for the beginning so I can move forward with the "assumption"
now I have to show it for

$a_{ 2(n+1)  }$ am i right with this?

I have no clue how to do it, I tried something and came with the induction hypothesis to this: =
$a_{ 2n } + \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ = $a_{ 2(n+1)  }$ =

I don't have any clue how to move forward from this.

which is basically $\frac{ a_{ 2n  }*2^{n}+1}{ 2^{ n } }$

I assume that due to my definition of the series, I can write :
$a_{ 2n+2  }$ as $\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n}}{2}$

I'm hoping for help, would really appreciate it!

Comment: $a_{2n+2}=\frac{a_{2n+1}+a_{2n}}{2}$ is the correct assumption

Answer (score 1):

We have $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{2}$.
Observe that if $n$ is even, say $n=2x$, then $$a_{2x-1}=2\cdot a_{2x} - a_{2x-2}$$

Now, using above equation, we can formulate an equation in terms of even indices as below. $$a_{2(n+1)}=\frac{a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}{2} 
= \frac{a_{2n}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}}{2} \Big)
= \frac{3}{4}(a_{2n})  + \frac{1}{4}(a_{2n-1}) 
= \frac{3}{4}(a_{2n})  + \frac{1}{4}(2\cdot a_{2n} - a_{2n-2}) 
= \frac{5}{4}(a_{2n})  - \frac{1}{4}(a_{2n-2}) $$

We have to show, $a_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}$.

The base case is true as for $n=1$, it becomes $a_2=\frac{a_1 + a_{0}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

On expanding $a_{2n+2}$, we have
$$a_{2(n+1)}=\frac{a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}}{2} 
= \frac{5}{4}(a_{2n})  - \frac{1}{4}(a_{2n-2}) 
= \frac{5}{4}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\Big)  - \frac{1}{4}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\Big) 
= \frac{5}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}} 
= \frac{1}{2^{2+2n-1}}+ \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}} $$
This proves the induction, as on solving $a_{2(n+1)}$ comes out to be $\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\Big) $.